# Break out of Bluebird promise chain in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I've studied several related questions & answers and still can't find the solution for what I'm trying to do. I'm using Mongoose with Bluebird for promises.

My promise chain involves 3 parts:

1. Get user 1 by username
2. If user 1 was found, get user 2 by username
3. If both user 1 and user 2 were found, store a new record

If either step 1 or step 2 fail to return a user, I don't want to do step 3. Failing to return a user, however, does not cause a database error, so I need to check for a valid user manually.

I can use `Promise.reject()` in step 1 and it will skip step 2, but will still execute step 3. Other answers suggest using `cancel()`, but I can't seem to make that work either.

My code is below. (My function `User.findByName()` returns a promise.)

```
var fromU,toU;
User.findByName('robfake').then((doc)=>{
        if (doc){
            fromU = doc;
            return User.findByName('bobbyfake');
        } else {
            console.log('user1');
            return Promise.reject('user1 not found');
        }       
    },(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    }).then((doc)=>{
        if (doc){
            toU = doc;
            var record = new LedgerRecord({
                transactionDate: Date.now(),
                fromUser: fromU,
                toUser: toU,
            });
            return record.save()
        } else {
            console.log('user2');
            return Promise.reject('user2 not found');
        }

    },(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    }).then((doc)=>{
        if (doc){
            console.log('saved');
        } else {
            console.log('new record not saved')
        }

    },(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example

All you need to do is something like this:

```
let findUserOrFail = name =>
    User.findByName(name).then(v => v || Promise.reject('not found'));

Promise.all(['robfake', 'bobbyfake'].map(findUserOrFail)).then(users => {
    var record = new LedgerRecord({
        transactionDate: Date.now(),
        fromUser: users[0],
        toUser: users[1],
    });
    return record.save();
}).then(result => {
    // result of successful save
}).catch(err => {
    // handle errors - both for users and for save
});
```

### More info

You can create a function:

```
let findUserOrFail = name =>
    User.findByName(name).then(v => v || Promise.reject('not found'));
```

and then you can use it like you want.

E.g. you can do:

```
Promise.all([user1, user1].map(findUserOrFail)).then(users => {
    // you have both users
}).catch(err => {
    // you don't have both users
});
```

That way will be faster because you don't have to wait for the first user to get the second one - both can be queried in parallel - and you can scale it to more users in the future:

```
let array = ['array', 'with', '20', 'users'];
Promise.all(array.map(findUserOrFail)).then(users => {
    // you have all users
}).catch(err => {
    // you don't have all users
});
```

No need to complicate it more than that.

Comment: This is looking good. I'm confused though about how I get the objects back from the db if I *do* find the user, however. Within the Promises.all block, how do I get the data for each user to then send into my next function?

Comment: @fredrover See my updated answer. Basically Promise.all returns a promise that gets resolved to an array of users - if both are found. See the `.then(users => {...})` part in the new example at the top.

Comment: Thank you! That's really nice. My remaining question is: where can I handle the result of `record.save()`, which is also a promise? For example, let's say I just wanted to log the message 'Saved Successfully'.

Comment: @fredrover See my updated answer - search for "result of successful save" - or you could also handle it directly after save - i.e. `...save().then(r => console.log('success')).catch(err => console.log('save error:', err));` The way I showed in my update now allows you to handle all errors in one place (for missing users, for errors getting users and for failure on save).

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

move your error handling out of the inner chain to the place you want to actual catch/handle it. As i don't have mongo installed, here is some pseudocode that should do the trick:

```
function findUser1(){
  return Promise.resolve({
    user: 1
  });
}

function findUser2(){
  return Promise.resolve({
    user: 2
  });
}

function createRecord(user1, user2){
  return Promise.resolve({
    fromUser: user1,
    toUser: user2,
  });
}

findUser1()
  .then(user1 => findUser2()
      .then(user2 => createRecord(user1, user2))) // better nest your promises as having variables in your outside scope
  .then(record => console.log('record created'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); // error is passed to here, every then chain until here gets ignored
```

Try it by changing findUser1 to

```
return Promise.reject('not found 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using `throw x;` instead of `return Promise.reject(x);`, simply for readibility reasons. Second, your error logging functions catch all the errors, that's why your promise chain is continuing. Try rethrowing the errors:

```
console.log(err);
throw err;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put error logging everywhere without actually *handling* the error - if you pass an error handler callback you'll get back a promise that will fulfill with `undefined`, which is not what you can need. Just use

```
User.findByName('robfake').then(fromUser => {
    if (fromUser) {
        return User.findByName('bobbyfake').then(toUser => {
            if (toUser) {
                var record = new LedgerRecord({
                    transactionDate: Date.now(),
                    fromUser,
                    toUser
                });
                return record.save()
            } else {
                console.log('user2 not found');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('user1 not found');
    }
}).then(doc => {
    if (doc) {
        console.log('saved', doc);
    } else {
        console.log('saved nothing')
    }
}, err => {
    console.error("something really bad happened somewhere in the chain", err);
});
```

This will always log one of the "saved" or "something bad" messages, and possibly one of the "not found" messages before.

You can also use exceptions to achieve this, but it doesn't really get simpler:

```
var user1 = User.findByName('robfake').then(fromUser => {
    if (fromUser)
        return fromUser;
    else
        throw new Error('user1 not found');
});
var user2 = user1.then(() => // omit this if you want them to be searched in parallel
    User.findByName('bobbyfake').then(toUser => {
        if (toUser)
            return toUser;
        else
            throw new Error('user2 not found');
    })
);

Promise.all([user1, user2]).then([fromUser, toUser]) =>
    var record = new LedgerRecord({
        transactionDate: Date.now(),
        fromUser,
        toUser
    });
    return record.save();
}).then(doc => {
    if (doc) {
        console.log('saved', doc);
    } else {
        console.log('saved nothing')
    }
}, err => {
    console.error(err.message);
});
```